# 'fatal error: linux/compiler-gcc5.h: No such file or directory' during bitbake

Tags: linux, gcc, yocto, bitbake, openembedded

I am attempting to run bitbake on a recipe with a non-yocto custom source. Using a linux-yocto source works fine, but when I attempt to use the linux-yocto-custom skeleton file provided by the yocto project files, I run into problems.

My file structure looks a little like this:

```
meta-test
|
.
.
.
+--recipes-kernel/
   |
   +--linux/
       |
       +--linux-yocto-custom_3.16.bb
       +--linux-yocto-custom/
          |
          +--defconfig
```

Here's my modified skeleton file (linux-yocto-custom_3.16.bb):

```
inherit kernel
require recipes-kernel/linux/linux-yocto.inc
SRC_URI = "git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git;protocol=git;nocheckout=1;name=machine"
SRC_URI += "file://defconfig"
LINUX_VERSION ?= "3.16"
LINUX_VERSION_EXTENSION_append = "-custom"
SRCREV_test="19583ca584d6f574384e17fe7613dfaeadcdc4a6"
PV = "${LINUX_VERSION}+git${SRCPV}"
COMPATIBLE_MACHINE = "test"
```

Here's the error log:

```
DEBUG: Executing shell function do_compile
NOTE: make -j 4 bzImage CC=i586-poky-linux-gcc  -fuse-ld=bfd LD=i586-poky-linux-ld.bfd 
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/me/poky/build/tmp/work/test-poky-linux/linux-yocto-custom/3.16+gitAUTOINC+19583ca584-r0/linux-test-standard-build'
  GEN     ./Makefile
scripts/kconfig/conf --silentoldconfig Kconfig
  SYSTBL  arch/x86/syscalls/../include/generated/asm/syscalls_32.h
  SYSHDR  arch/x86/syscalls/../include/generated/uapi/asm/unistd_32.h
  CHK     include/config/kernel.release
  SYSHDR  arch/x86/syscalls/../include/generated/uapi/asm/unistd_64.h
  UPD     include/config/kernel.release
  SYSHDR  arch/x86/syscalls/../include/generated/uapi/asm/unistd_x32.h
  GEN     ./Makefile
  WRAP    arch/x86/include/generated/asm/clkdev.h
  WRAP    arch/x86/include/generated/asm/early_ioremap.h
  WRAP    arch/x86/include/generated/asm/cputime.h
  WRAP    arch/x86/include/generated/asm/mcs_spinlock.h
  CHK     include/generated/uapi/linux/version.h
  UPD     include/generated/uapi/linux/version.h
  CHK     include/generated/utsrelease.h
  UPD     include/generated/utsrelease.h
  HOSTCC  scripts/kallsyms
  HOSTCC  scripts/pnmtologo
  CC      scripts/mod/empty.o
  HOSTCC  scripts/mod/mk_elfconfig
  CC      scripts/mod/devicetable-offsets.s
In file included from /home/me/poky/build/tmp/work-shared/test/kernel-source/include/linux/compiler.h:54:0,
                 from /home/me/poky/build/tmp/work-shared/test/kernel-source/include/uapi/linux/stddef.h:1,
                 from /home/me/poky/build/tmp/work-shared/test/kernel-source/include/linux/stddef.h:4,
                 from /home/me/poky/build/tmp/work-shared/test/kernel-source/include/uapi/linux/posix_types.h:4,
                 from /home/me/poky/build/tmp/work-shared/test/kernel-source/include/uapi/linux/types.h:13,
                 from /home/me/poky/build/tmp/work-shared/test/kernel-source/include/linux/types.h:5,
                 from /home/me/poky/build/tmp/work-shared/test/kernel-source/include/linux/mod_devicetable.h:11,
                 from /home/me/poky/build/tmp/work-shared/test/kernel-source/scripts/mod/devicetable-offsets.c:2:
/home/me/poky/build/tmp/work-shared/test/kernel-source/include/linux/compiler-gcc.h:106:30: fatal error: linux/compiler-gcc5.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make[4]: *** [scripts/mod/devicetable-offsets.s] Error 1
make[3]: *** [scripts/mod] Error 2
make[3]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make[2]: *** [scripts] Error 2
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make[1]: *** [sub-make] Error 2
make: *** [__sub-make] Error 2
WARNING: /home/me/poky/build/tmp/work/test-poky-linux/linux-yocto-custom/3.16+gitAUTOINC+19583ca584-r0/temp/run.do_compile.32722:1 exit 1 from
  exit 1
ERROR: oe_runmake failed
ERROR: Function failed: do_compile (log file is located at /home/me/poky/build/tmp/work/test-poky-linux/linux-yocto-custom/3.16+gitAUTOINC+19583ca584-r0/temp/log.do_compile.32722)
```

I believe the most relevant portion is this part of the above log:

```
compiler-gcc.h:106:30: fatal error: linux/compiler-gcc5.h: No such file or directory
```

I'm really stumped because a file is generated during the build 'compiler-gcc5.h' at location `build/tmp/work/test-poky-linux/core-image-test/1.0-r0/rootfs/usr/src/kernel/include/linux/compiler-gcc5.h`. What's going on here? It seems to me that this header file's being requested before being fetched but I don't know how to fix that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you're fetching the kernel directly from Linus' tree, the 3.16 version does not support building with gcc5.

If you change to instead fetch from `git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git`, i.e. the stable tree, and change to v3.16.7:

```
SRC_URI = "git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git;protocol=git;nocheckout=1;name=machine;branch=linux-3.16.y"
SRCREV_test = "d0335e4feea0d3f7a8af3116c5dc166239da7521"
```

then you should be able to build the kernel without any issue.

Comment: I'm trying to build Linux kernel v2.6... getting the same error but with gcc 6... will this solution work for me as well?